# Nested for loops won't evaluate

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm making an javascript image converter, just a proof of concept(I know there are another better languages for doing it). My problem is that in the loop section I'm doing some variables don't evaluate to the ones that are in the function loops. The code should work this way:

1. The HTML button activates the parent function.
2. Some variables are stated.
3. The loop that should make a nice gradient all over the  and those I'm having trouble with are defined.
4. A function that triggers the loops in intervals is stated, with some other counter variables.e

I think the problem is in the counter variables I use on the loop() but I can't figure them out.

Here is all my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>CPBitmap to PNG</title>

<style>

  #canvas {
      width:512px;
      height:384px;
      background-color:black;
  }

</style>

<script>
function convertir(){
    var y =0;
    vertC = 10;
    var pixelConverter = function(){
        for(;y<vertC;y++){
            for(var x=0; x<2048;x++){
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                var pixel = "rgb(" + y + "," + vertC + "," + x + ")";
                ctx.fillStyle = pixel;
                ctx.fillRect(x,y,100,100);      
            }       
        }               
    }
    intervalos = setInterval(loops,1);
    function loops(){
        pixelConverter();
        vertC = vertC + 10;
        console.log("Y= " + y + "Linea " + vertC );
        y = y + 10;
        x = 0;
        console.log(x);
        if(x > 2047 && y > 1535)intervalos=window.clearInterval(intervalos);
        else pixelConverter();



    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body>


<input type="file" id="input" name="file" /> 

<button onclick=convertir() >¡Convertir!</button>

<button onclick="intervalos=window.clearInterval(intervalos)">Alto</button>

<canvas id="canvas" width="2048px" height="1536px"></canvas>


<div id="Hola"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I created a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/TvPyP/ but I'm not sure what I should see. I see a blue gradient at the top, and the console is logging like crazy.

Comment: Sorry I made the the logging just for debugging, but the purpose of this code is to create the blue gradient all over the canvas, but it is only making it at the top. I have the problem that the variable "y" is in charge of vertical alingment, but when the loop is finished the variable "y" doesn't increase.